# Can't choose asp.net web service application in VS 2010 when .net 4.0 is chosen?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Can't you have a .net 4.0 web service application? When I choose .net 3.5 the "asp.net web service application" shows up in the list but once I change it back to 4.0 it goes away. Did something replace it or they just don't have a webservice at 4.0 yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same template in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Just create a 3.5 WebService-project and afterwards change it's framework to 4.0